# Iterating an array of strings: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have an array of strings of different lengths, and I want to iterate all of the arrays to check for the LongestCommonPrefix (an 'easy' leetcode.com problem).
I find it hard to avoid the error (given in the title of this Q), but (with my knowledge) it seems inconsistent. To explore the issues, I've tried this:

```
    l = ["str","string"];
    longest = l[1].length;
    // some 2nd level string elements do not exist in the array
    for (i = 0; i < longest; i++) {
        console.log('typeof: ', i, typeof  l[0][i]);
    }

    // the 3rd array element has not been defined / initialised
    for (i = 0; i < l[0].length + 1; i++) {
        console.log('typeof: ', i, typeof  l[3][i]);
    }
```

and get this result:

```
    typeof:  0 string
    typeof:  1 string
    typeof:  2 string
    typeof:  3 undefined
    typeof:  4 undefined
    typeof:  5 undefined
    /Volumes/some_path/testarray.js:11
        console.log('typeof: ', i, typeof  l[3][i]);
                                               ^

    TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
        at Object.<anonymous> 

    (/Volumes/some_path/testarray.js:11:44)
    ...
```

Why does the first pass iterate over the array and return 'undefined', and yet the second pass (deliberately attempting to iterate over element [3], which has not been defined) fails.
And how do I successfully handle that error without a run-time error?

Comment: You do realize that longest is for the second string, but you're trying to iterate over the first.

Comment: @Musa Yes - that's deliberate to ensure I run over the end of the first string and prove that it successfully returns 'undefined' without failing, and hence contrasts with the second iteration which causes a run-time error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to access a non-existent property of an object¹ you will get undefined.
However, if you try to access a property of null or undefined you will get a type error.

`l[3]` is undefined so trying to access property `0` gives you an error, however, l[0] is neither undefined or null so you can try to access whatever property you want which will return the value if it exists or undefined if it doesn't(or does exist but set to undefined).

¹ Same goes for primitives as they will be promoted to objects to have access to properties.

Comment: thanks for that - that explains why a test 'typeof' doesn't catch the l[3] error. Q - is ...try .. catch... the only or best way to avoid the run-time error?